# Android & Eclispe - Export Signed application no longer works

Tags: android

All of a sudden I cannot export a signed application in eclipse

Right Click -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package

Nothing happens, I can still install it on the emulator and export an Unsigned package

What is going wrong?

I get the following in the error log when I press the "Export Signed Application Package" menu item

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0
>   2010-09-12 02:50:14.734 !MESSAGE
>   WARNING: Blocked recursive attempt to
>   close part
>   org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor while
>   still in the middle of activating it
>   !STACK 0 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   WARNING: Blocked recursive attempt to
>   close part
>   org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor while
>   still in the middle of activating it
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:1300)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1435)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.doHide(EditorPane.java:61)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.close(PartStack.java:543)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.close(EditorStack.java:206)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.close(PartStack.java:122)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:83)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:270)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:279)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$1.closeButtonPressed(DefaultTabFolder.java:70)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder.notifyCloseListeners(PaneFolder.java:626)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder$3.close(PaneFolder.java:206)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:2199)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:327)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:327)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.handleEditorInputChanged(AbstractTextEditor.java:4632)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.handleEditorInputChanged(StatusTextEditor.java:233)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.sanityCheckState(AbstractTextEditor.java:4784)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.sanityCheckState(StatusTextEditor.java:223)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.safelySanityCheckState(AbstractTextEditor.java:4762)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$ActivationListener.handleActivation(AbstractTextEditor.java:987)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$ActivationListener.partActivated(AbstractTextEditor.java:944)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList$1.run(PartListenerList.java:72)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.fireEvent(PartListenerList.java:57)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.firePartActivated(PartListenerList.java:70)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartActivated(PartService.java:187)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.setActivePart(PartService.java:306)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.updateActivePart(WWinPartService.java:131)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.access$0(WWinPartService.java:122)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService$WWinListener.partDeactivated(WWinPartService.java:50)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2$4.run(PartListenerList2.java:115)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.fireEvent(PartListenerList2.java:55)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.firePartDeactivated(PartListenerList2.java:113)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartDeactivated(PartService.java:242)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.setActivePart(PartService.java:300)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.fireActivePartChanged(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:57)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.setActivePart(PartList.java:136)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3531)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.requestActivation(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:279)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.requestActivation(EditorPane.java:98)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setFocus(PresentablePart.java:192)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:94)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:270)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:275)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.handleMouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:345)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder$3.mouseDown(AbstractTabFolder.java:79)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:179)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
>
> !ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0
>   2010-09-12 02:50:27.661 !MESSAGE
>   Failed to load properties file for
>   project 'MainMenuActivity'
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-09-12
>   02:50:27.662 !MESSAGE Unhandled event
>   loop exception !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectChooserHelper$NonLibraryProjectOnlyFilter.accept(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.BaseProjectHelper.getAndroidProjects(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.BaseProjectHelper.getAndroidProjects(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectChooserHelper.getAndroidProjects(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ProjectCheckPage.handleProjectNameChange(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ProjectCheckPage.access$0(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ProjectCheckPage$1.modifyText(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:167)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2526)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4082)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:3949)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4589)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native
>   Method)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2313)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:255)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4036)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2170)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4589)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native
>   Method)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3264)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:1961)
>    at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ProjectCheckPage.onShow(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$ExportWizardPage.setVisible(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1199)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:551)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
>    at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.ExportWizardAction.run(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
>    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:13

11)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I dont remember exactly how I solved it... Try refresh the project then Project > Clean and restart Eclipse.

Comment: I tried that, I even restarted the computer but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, there was another project called MainMenuActivity (I don't know where this came from), it contained not files whatsoever.  I deleted this project and now everything works.